# "Yet" meaning "already"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-choice

I was writing a message to a friend. She was going to arrive to my country one of these days. I was about to ask:

> Are you here yet?

But then I thought, "Is that a 'legal' question?" Judging from [context.reverso.net](https://context.reverso.net/translation/english-russian/are+you+yet) it probably is. One can see there:

> Are you finished yet?

But I don't think (judging from dictionaries) "yet" can ever mean "already." It's probably closer to "not already."

My conjecture here is that "are you here already?" is a neutral question. But if I use "yet" instead, it's like, "I've been waiting for you for a couple of days now. Haven't you arrived yet?" Meaning, "yet" makes it more emotional, conveys a feeling of longing or something.

To sum it up. Can I use "yet" in the above mentioned context? If so, what would it mean? If not, what is a better phrasing?

Comment: Can 'yet' ever mean 'already'? Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/yet) "Adverb **yet²** Still; even (used to emphasize increase or repetition). *Snow, snow, and yet more snow*."

Comment: Re the main question, 'yet' can show impatience, but "Have you arrived?" seems too curt. Perhaps you can say "Please tell me when [or as soon as] you get here."

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed, my question is probably a bit messy (think, mixed-up thoughts). If "Are you here yet?" is a correct question, then in this case "yet" can be replaced with "already." Except that then we lose a notion of impatience. Which means "yet" can have a meaning close to "already" in questions. And that would probably be the first meaning [here](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/yet_1?q=yet), not the third one. Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, the first meaning.

Comment: "... Haven't you arrived yet?" was my attempt to rephrase "Are you here yet?" Too curt? Even among friends? To be frank, "Please tell me when..." sounds like what would put in a business email or something. Just thinking aloud. But okay, thanks for the correction, I'll try to keep that in mind.

Comment: Phrasing as a negative question can sound impatient, or even annoyed. "Are you here yet?" is good, especially if followed by something to take the edge off it, such as "I can't wait to see you!"

Comment: Fyi more usual is: Aren't you here yet? Haven't you finished yet? for the meanings suggested by your question. **yet** is not more emotional. It means: up to this point in time. And it never means "already".

Comment: "Are you here already?" implies surprise that the person is here so soon.

Comment: "Fyi more usual is: Aren't you here yet? for the meanings suggested by your question." I wonder why "aren't" is more fitting? And when would one use "are"? Has it something to do with expectations? From what I can see the difference is that "aren't" expresses a [stronger emotion](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/yet).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Yet* means *already* in a clause with a [negative polarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item) context. Despite the name, such contexts include questions as well as negative statements.

So *any* can occur in NP contexts:

> There aren't **any** trees here.

> Are there **any** trees here?

but not

> *There are any trees here.

and so can *yet*:

> I haven't seen him **yet**.

> Have you seen him **yet**?

but not

> *I have seen him yet.